# Erro Wrong number of arguments em ambiente de produção

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

Estou com uma aplicação em desenvolvimento e produção, e somente no modo de produção esta apresentando o seguinte erro:

> [0m[31m13:11:45,758 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-118) UT005023: Exception handling request to /1/registers/object/new: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Como posso corrigir esse problema no ambiente de produção que esta funcionando na Locaweb com o serviço Jelastic? Penso que é algo no próprio Wildfly que esta rodando nesse servidor, versão 9.0. Logo que é apresentado esse erro o usuário volta para a tela de login e não é possível cadastrar um novo objeto porque ao voltar a efetuar a requisição nessa URL ocorre novamente o problema.

**ObjectController.class**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registers/object")
@ControllerLabel(label="header.registers.object")
public class ObjectController extends GenericController<Object> {

    @Autowired
    public ObjectController(ObjectService service) {
        super(service, Object.class, "object", "protected/registers/ListObject", "protected/registers/CrudObject");
    }

    @ModelAttribute("EnumTipoObject" )
    public List<EnumTipoObject> getEnumTipoObject() {
        return Arrays.asList(EnumTipoObject.values());
    }
}
```

**GenericController.class**:

```
public abstract class GenericController <T>  {

    protected final Class<T> classBean;
    private final String nameVarBean;   
    protected final GenericService<T> service;
    private final String jspList;
    private final String jspManager;

    public GenericController(GenericService<T> service,Class<T> classBean,String nameVarBean, String jspList,String jspManager) {
        this.service = service;
        this.classBean = classBean;
        this.jspList = jspList;
        this.jspManager = jspManager;
        this.nameVarBean = nameVarBean;
    }

    @Link(label="New", family="genericcontroller", parent = "Lista") 
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final String viewCreate(Model model) throws Exception{

        model.addAttribute(nameVarBean,service.getInstanceOfObjectT(classBean) );

        return jspManager;      
    }

    @Link(label="Lista", family="genericcontroller", parent = "") 
    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final String viewList() {
        return jspList;     
    }

    @Link(label="Alterar", family="genericcontroller", parent = "Lista") 
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/alterar/{oid}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final ModelAndView viewUpdate(@PathVariable("oid") Long oid, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{   

        T vObject = service.findOne(oid);   
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(jspManager); 

        if(vObject != null) {       
            mv.addObject(nameVarBean, vObject);


            return mv;      
        }else { 
            String urlRed = request.getServletPath().substring(1, request.getServletPath().lastIndexOf("/alterar"));


            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/" + urlRed + "/novo");
        }   
    }   

    @Link(label="Salvar", family="genericcontroller", parent = "Lista") 
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/salvar", "/alterar/salvar"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public final String save( @Valid T object , BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request ){

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return jspManager;
         }  

         try {
             service.save(object, request); 
         }catch (Exception e) {
             result.addError(ExceptionFilter.filterMessage2(e, request));
             return jspManager; 
         }


         String urlRed = request.getServletPath().substring(1, request.getServletPath().lastIndexOf("/"));

         if (urlRed.lastIndexOf("alterar") > 0)
             urlRed = request.getServletPath().substring(1, request.getServletPath().lastIndexOf("/alterar"));

         return "redirect:/" + urlRed ; 
    }

    @Link(label="Alterar", family="genericcontroller", parent = "Lista") 
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/alterar/deletar"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public final String delete(T object , BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request ){

        try{
            service.delete(object, request);    

            String urlRed = request.getServletPath().substring(1, request.getServletPath().lastIndexOf("/alterar"));


             return "redirect:/" + urlRed ; 

        }catch(Exception e) {       

            result.addError(ExceptionFilter.filterMessage2(e, request));
            return jspManager;          
        }    
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/listTable"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Iterable<T> listTable(int offset, int limit,@RequestParam(value = "search",required = false) String search,
            @RequestParam(value = "sort",required = false)  String sort, String order){
        Iterable<T>a =  service.findPaginationTable(offset,limit,order,sort,search); 
        return a;        
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/listSelect"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Iterable<T> listSelectSearch(@RequestParam(value = "term",required = false)  String term, @RequestParam(value = "id",required = false) Long id) throws Exception{

        List<T> i;

        if (id != null) {
            i = new ArrayList<T>();
            i.add(service.findOne(id));        
        } else {
            i = service.findSelectSearch(term.toUpperCase()); 
        }

        return i;       
    }  

}
```

**Log**:

```
[0m[31m13:11:45,758 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-118) UT005023: Exception handling request to /1/registers/object/new: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.econtabil.erp.generic.GenericService.getInstanceOfObjectT(GenericService.java:24)
    at com.econtabil.erp.generic.GenericController.viewCreate(GenericController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: Giancarlo, a aplicação é um web service? Posta o método de cadastro e código relacionados.

Comment: Não é um webservice, posto sim.

Comment: Local você está rodando em um *servlet container* ou no WF também? Pela *stack trace* parece ser problema ser problemas nas bibliotecas dos ambiente. Recomendaria dar uma olhada nas `servlet-api` e a(s) de EL. Sem mais detalhes sobre os ambientes não dá para reproduzir :)